# Can I re-use an expression in a MySQL query as a variable for another field?

Tags: mysql

Is there any workaround so I can actually do something like this without having to repeat the entire expression or force a UNION or temporary table?

```
SELECT  (complex expression) AS variable1,
        (complex expression based on variable1) AS variable2
```

Since variable1 is not defined and available to the 2nd item because of how mysql works, the above concept can never work.

I either have to repeat the expression for variable2, or use a UNION or a temporary table and use two passes.

Is there some trick that I am not aware of to accomplish this more efficiently?

(note that I need to know the answer for both variable1 and variable2 as they are then used for an INSERT)

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I resuse a calculated field in a SELECT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085443/can-i-resuse-a-calculated-field-in-a-select-query)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

push the first calculation in to a derived table:

```
select variable1
     , complex_function(variable1, other_column) as variable2
     , yet_another column
  from (select complex_operation as variable1
             , other_column
             , yet_another_column
          from whatever) dt
```

Comment: It's messier than I wanted but I am going to give you best answer for all your effort, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT @v1:=(complex expression) AS variable1,
       (complex expression * @v1) AS variable2
```

Comment: I am going to be horrified if it's simply that easy and I honestly couldn't figure it out, but thank you!

Comment: Ah, you know what? The manual page listed above by knittl has repeated warnings not to use or rely on variables set in the same SELECT statement as the fields may be executed out of order based on the WHERE, etc. and the variable is held from the previous execution.

So re-using variables within the same SELECT is probably a bad idea, it's meant for sequential queries.

Comment: i've personally never seen the behavior warned about in the manual, even after trying to make it happen. but if the manual warns against it, then i wouldn't use it. *bleh*

Comment: I can confirm that this solution does not work, as in my case it was reusing the value set in the previous query. Downvoted.

Comment: If that's the case then you didn't use this exact query. If you have a problem with your query then you should ask a new question instead of voting down an answer that you mis-used.

Comment: Except that as @ck_ mentioned, the documentation explicitly says not to do this: "As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.". So this is wrong and still deserves a downvote, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i think the only way is to repeat your first complex_expression in your second one, although i thought mysql could handle such cases.

edit: a quick search turned up this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, somehow I completely missed that part of MySQL!

Comment: Your link to the manual was very helpful in understanding why longneck's solution was flawed, thanks again.