# How to combine two count queries to their ratio?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two queries:

```
select count(*) from my_table where status="accepted"
```

and

```
select count(*) from my_table where status="rejected"
```

I was to find the ratio of accepted/reject so I Was wondering if it's possible to combine the two queries so I don't have to execute two queries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904741/getting-difference-between-counts-of-two-subqueries?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting this answer since none offered so far is correct

```
select count(case when status = "accepted" then 1 end) /
       count(case when status = "rejected" then 1 end) as Ratio
from my_table
where status in ("accepted","rejected")
```

If you also need the individual counts

```
select count(case when status = "accepted" then 1 end) Accepted,
       count(case when status = "rejected" then 1 end) Rejected,
       count(case when status = "accepted" then 1 end) /
       count(case when status = "rejected" then 1 end) as Ratio
from my_table
where status in ("accepted","rejected")
```

**Note: MySQL does not have a divide by zero problem.  It returns NULL when Rejected is 0.**

Comment: Maybe we can reuse accepted and rejected somehow to get the ratio? As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1368135/895245

Answer (score 2):

```
select accepted_count, rejected_count, accepted_count/rejected_count ratio
from (
    select sum(CASE WHEN status="accepted" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) accepted_count,
           sum(CASE WHEN status="rejected" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) rejected_count
    from my_table 
    ) A
```

Comment: yeah great explanation, it was clear I meant SUM, no need to -1

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT (Select count(*) from my_table where status="accepted") / (select count(*) from my_table where status="rejected") AS ratio
```

Comment: Thanks. Although other solutions worked. This was simplest and seems to be fast

Comment: @richard you posted a bit late so I was trying the other queries. Yours actually performs a bit better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select status, count(*) from my_table 
where status in ("rejected", "accepted")
group by status;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(case when status='accepted' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedCount,
       sum(case when status='rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedCount
    from my_table
```