# Difference between two COUNTS

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a mysql table `private_messages` (`pm`) that looks like this:

userid --- sender --- text

While Userid and Sender are both IDs from the table `user`.
Now I want to do a query where a user gets the difference between the amount of pms he sent to another user and the received pms from this one - grouped by `Userid`
So I want to put those two queries in one and get the different out of it:

```
SELECT count(*) AS s_count, sender FROM pm WHERE userid=".$userid" GROUP BY sender
SELECT count(*) AS u_count, userid FROM pm WHERE sender=".$userid." GROUP BY userid
```

and now I want the difference between`s_count` and `u_count` on all matching Userids.

Comment: Why do you want to use group by if you are using count *

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462961/how-to-combine-two-count-queries-to-their-ratio?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want statistics per user you've corresponded with, you can just collect all messages using `UNION ALL` and sum them in an outer query;

```sql
SELECT counterpart, SUM(sent) sent, SUM(received) received,
       SUM(sent) - SUM(received) difference
FROM (
  SELECT 1 sent, 0 received, userid counterpart 
  FROM messages WHERE sender = <your user id>
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 sent, 1 received, sender counterpart
  FROM messages WHERE userid = <your user id>
) a
GROUP BY counterpart;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/986ab/3).

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly well! And could you tell me how I would add a where-clause so it only selects rows where difference > 0?

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister You can just add a `HAVING SUM(sent) <> SUM(received)` to the end of the query, after the `GROUP BY` line.

Answer (score 1):

You would be wise to add to your select list any column(s) over which you group the results:

```sql
SELECT sender, COUNT(*) AS s_count FROM pm WHERE userid = ? GROUP BY sender
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS u_count FROM pm WHERE sender = ? GROUP BY userid
```

You will then see that the first query returns the number of messages with the given `userid`, broken down by `sender`; whereas the second query returns the number of messages with the given `sender`, broken down by `userid`.  As such, it doesn't make much sense to combine these queries "*and get the difference out of it*".

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT count(*) FROM pm WHERE userid=".$userid" GROUP BY sender) AS s_count,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM pm WHERE sender=".$userid." GROUP BY userid) AS u_count,
    (SELECT s_count - u_count) AS result
```