# reusing alias in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What I am trying to do is add another column that calculates (cr - dr)

Seeing as you cannot re-use an alias inside a SELECT clause, how would you go about calculatin `total`

```
    SELECT SUM(b.bet_win * cy.fx_rate )as dr, SUM(b.bet_loss * cy.fx_rate ) as cr, cr+dr as total
    FROM ....
    WHERE ....
```

Comment: It's a shame your suggested sytax is illegal in Standard SQL because such flexibility would be useful. FWIW yours would be valid syntax in Access (ACE, Jet, whatever), however Access requires the expressions to be evaluated left-to-right and column ordering just makes SQL even more inflexible than it already is :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I resuse a calculated field in a SELECT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085443/can-i-resuse-a-calculated-field-in-a-select-query)

Answer (score 14):

In SQL Server or Oracle, I'd use a CTE, but since you're using MySQL, you'd use a subquery:

```
SELECT dr, cr, cr + dr as total 
FROM (
    SELECT 
         SUM(b.bet_win * cy.fx_rate ) as dr, 
         SUM(b.bet_loss * cy.fx_rate ) as cr
    FROM ....
    WHERE ....) t;
```

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: DOES NOT WORK. See comments.
Isn't using a [user variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) faster in this case?

```
SELECT
  @dr:=SUM(b.bet_win * cy.fx_rate ),
  @cr:=SUM(b.bet_loss * cy.fx_rate ), 
  @cr+@dr as total
```

Comment: User-defined variables don't work that way, at least in MySQL. The value of @dr and @cr don't get set until *after* the row has been processed. When it builds the first row of the result set @dr is NULL and @cr is NULL, so `total` is NULL. Then @dr is set to the sum of wins, and @cr the sum of losses. When it builds the second row and calculates `total` @dr and @cr have the values of the previous row. So `total` will be the total for the previous row.

Comment: Wow, indeed! The mysql manual editors should put this at top of the page in stead of so much later. Thanks, jtanium, for letting us know.

Answer (score -1):

You can repeat the calculations in the "total" column.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(b.bet_win * cy.fx_rate) as dr, 
    SUM(b.bet_loss * cy.fx_rate) as cr, 
    SUM(b.bet_win * cy.fx_rate) + SUM(b.bet_loss * cy.fx_rate) as total
FROM ....
WHERE ....
```