# Using Column Alias in Same SELECT Clause

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to use a column alias in the same SELECT clause which it is being assigned? For example:

```
SELECT ord_id, candy_id, price, quantity, 
price * quantity AS ext_cost, ext_cost * @tax_rate
```

returns an error because MySQL does not recognize "`ext_cost`" in the `ext_cost * @tax_rate` query. If it is not possible, is possible to return a table with everything listed in the first query without having to write something like this?

```
SELECT ord_id, candy_id, price, quantity, 
price * quantity AS ext_cost, (price * quantity) * @tax_rate
```

Basically, I was just wondering if there was anyway to reuse `ext_cost` in the SELECT query.

Comment: you can possibly check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072479/reusing-alias-in-select

Answer (score 38):

No there isn't a way to refer to aliases, but you can assign the expression to a variable, and then refer to the variable in the same select clause.

Inside a select statement variable assignment is always done by the infix operator `:=`. *In a `SET` statement, it can be either `=` or `:=`.

e.g.

```
SELECT 
    ord_id
  , candy_id
  , price
  , quantity
  , @exc_cost := price * quantity AS exc_cost
  , @exc_cost * @tax_rate AS my_favourite_field
...
<FROM CLAUSE>
```

You can also conditionally perform variable assignment.

e.g.

```
IF(quantity > 90, 
     @exc_cost := price * quantity * 0.95
   , @exc_cost := price * quantity) AS exc_cost
```

Note 1: In the absence of aggregate measures & group by clause, the variables are evaluated according to column order:

```
SELECT @t, @t+2 FROM (SELECT @t := 1) a
```

produces the output

```
@t   @t+2
 1      3
```

Comment: Won't the variable only be assigned after the row is processed?

Comment: for better understanding of it refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715504/mysql-define-a-variable-within-select-and-use-it-within-the-same-select

Comment: The approach you took here is great but your answer would be better if you removed the false statement at the beginning: "*No there isn't a way to refer to aliases*".

Comment: Why do you say it's false, MySQL does not support lateral aliasing, and the approach shown in this post comes with major caveats

Answer (score 20):

In MySQL you CAN reference a select column alias in the same select, as long as it precedes the reference point.

```sql
SELECT 
    ord_id,
    candy_id,
    price,
    quantity, 
    price * quantity AS ext_cost,
    (SELECT ext_cost) * @tax_rate as retail_rate
```

Now if only I knew how to do this in postgres.

Comment: You can use lateral joins in postgres for aliasing expressions

Comment: @HaleemurAli yes you can, but it's nowhere near as readable or easy, and has completely different behaviour.

Comment: So simple and working but, How Can I do this in SQL Server??

Comment: What is this technique called, and is it described in the MySQL docs?

Comment: FYI: in Snowflake, you can simply reference the alias in subsequent column definitions. No funky syntax required. Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Using a subquery

```
SELECT t1.ord_id, t1.candy_id, t1.price, t1.quantity, t2.ext_cost, t2.ext_cost * @tax_rate
FROM table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT t.ord_id, t.price * t.quantity AS ext_cost FROM table1 t) t2
ON t2.ord_id = t1.ord_id
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've always tried avoiding subqueries because I have problems with them, but I guess I'll have to just learn how to deal with them one day.