# Use a column created using AS to do aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

Can MySQL detect the columns created using AS?

Example;

```
SUM( Mark1 + Mark2) AS '2022_SUM'
SUM( Mark3 + Mark4) AS '2021_SUM'
(2022_SUM + 2021_SUM) AS 'SUM1'
```

It hits unknown column in field list.

Comment: Please provide a **complete** SQL statement., and take a look at [Using Column Alias in Same SELECT Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860303/using-column-alias-in-same-select-clause)

Comment: Hi Luuk, thanks. Using a user defined variable makes it so the sum of the current row has the sum of the previous row. Any way to solve this?

Comment: "Using a user defined variable"  I cannot see what you are doing with user defined variables, which seems not needed here.

Comment: Sorry, i was referring to the link you gave me. they use a variable to solve column alias not being able to be detected by select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```sql
SELECT
   SUM(Mark1 + Mark2) as '2022_SUM',
   SUM(Mark3 + Mark4) as '2021_SUM',
   SUM(Mark1 + Mark2) + SUM(Mark3 + Mark4) as 'SUM1'
FROM someTableName
```

OR

```sql
SELECT
   2022_SUM,
   2021_SUM,
   2022_SUM + 2021_SUM as 'SUM1'
FROM (
   SELECT
      SUM(Mark1 + Mark2) as '2022_SUM',
      SUM(Mark3 + Mark4) as '2021_SUM'
   FROM someTableName 
) x
```