# How to check length of Redshift (postgres) regexp_substr output?

Tags: regex, postgresql, amazon-redshift

```
SELECT
    data
    ,regexp_substr(data,'bottle~([[:alnum:]]{32})', 1, 1, 'ep') as bval
    ,len(bval) as WhyIsntThisAlways32or0
FROM activity
WHERE TRUE
;
```

Data records look like this: `bottle~6c3f28d9f93e9000119cd9063d07d115~984983`

This query properly returns `bval` properly as `6c3f28d9f93e9000119cd9063d07d115`

However, `WhyIsntThisAlways32or0` never shows as the actual length. It's always either zero or one.

Why can't I, and how do I fix, checking for the length of a substring that was pulled out via regexp?

Related: this is a wildly oversimplified and redacted query. I believe need regexp_substr because doing other substring and position based splitting gets wicked real fast.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Column Alias in Same SELECT Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860303/using-column-alias-in-same-select-clause)

Comment: Is there a `bval` column in `activity`? Redshift will prioritize actual columns over aliases (see [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_list.html#:~:text=If%20there%20is%20a%20column%20with%20the%20same%20name%20defined%20in%20the%20FROM%20clause%20as%20the%20previously%20aliased%20expression%2C%20the%20column%20in%20the%20FROM%20clause%20takes%20priority) (edit: looks like linking to a specific text section doesn't work, but the info is in the note in the `AS column_alias` part)).