# SQL: Reuse function result in query without using sub-query

Tags: mysql, performance

In a MySQL DB table that stores sale orders, I have a `LastReviewed` column that holds the last date and time when the sale order was modified (type `timestamp`, default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`). I'd like to plot the number of sales that were modified each day, for the last 90 days, for a particular user.

I'm trying to craft a `SELECT` that returns the number of days since `LastReviewed` date, and how many records fall within that range.  Below is my query, which works just fine:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), LastReviewed) AS days, COUNT(*) AS number FROM sales
WHERE UserID=123 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),LastReviewed)<=90
GROUP BY days
ORDER BY days ASC
```

Notice that I am computing the `DATEDIFF()` as well as `CURDATE()` multiple times for each record.  This seems really ineffective, so I'd like to know how I can reuse the results of the previous computation.  The first thing I tried was:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), LastReviewed) AS days, COUNT(*) AS number FROM sales
WHERE UserID=123 AND days<=90
GROUP BY days
ORDER BY days ASC
```

Error: `Unknown column 'days' in 'where clause'`. So I started to look around the net. Based on another discussion ([Can I reuse a calculated field in a SELECT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085443/can-i-reuse-a-calculated-field-in-a-select-query)), I next tried the following:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), LastReviewed) AS days, COUNT(*) AS number FROM sales
WHERE UserID=123 AND (SELECT days)<=90
GROUP BY days
ORDER BY days ASC
```

Error: `Unknown column 'days' in 'field list'`.  I'm also tried the following:

```
SELECT @days := DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), LastReviewed) AS days, 
       COUNT(*) AS number FROM sales
WHERE UserID=123 AND @days <=90
GROUP BY days
ORDER BY days ASC
```

The query returns zero result, so `@days<=90` seems to return `false` even though if I put it in the `SELECT` clause and remove the `WHERE` clause, I can see some results with `@days` values below 90.

I've gotten things to work by using a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),LastReviewed) AS sales , 
         COUNT(*) AS number FROM sales
  WHERE UserID=123
  GROUP BY days
) AS t
WHERE days<=90
ORDER BY days ASC
```

However I odn't know whether it's the most efficient way. Not to mention that even this solution computes `CURDATE()` once per record even though its value will be the same from the start to the end of the query. Isn't that wasteful?  Am I overthinking this? Help would be welcome.

Note: Mods, should this be on CodeReview? I posted here because the code I'm trying to use doesn't actually work

Comment: FWIW, your query + subquery is not _expensive_ and you can check whether doing `WHERE days < 90` in the query OR repeating `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),LastReviewed)` gives results faster.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my post (I'll add it in a minute), but another thing that bugs me is that I compute `CURDATE()` at every step even though it won't change from the start to the end of the query.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two problems with your question.

First, you're overlooking the fact that `WHERE` precedes `SELECT`.  When the server evaluates `WHERE <expression>`, it then already knows the value of the calculations done to evaluate `<expression>` and can use those for `SELECT`.

Worse than that, though, you should almost never write a query that uses a column as an argument to a function, since that usually requires the server to evaluate the expression for each row.

Instead, you should use this:

```
WHERE LastReviewed < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

The optimizer will see this and get all excited, because `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)` can be resolved to a constant, which can be used on one side of a `<` comparison, which means that if an index exists with `LastReviewed` as the leftmost relevant column, then the server can immediately eliminate all of the rows with LastReviewed `>=` that constant value, using the index.

Then `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), LastReviewed) AS days` (still needed for `SELECT`) will only be evaluated against the rows we already know we want.

Add a single index on (UserID, LastReviewed) and the server will be able to pinpoint exactly the relevant rows extremely quickly.

Comment: Your post was a really good lesson for me; you're right I never considered that `WHERE` is executed first or the implication of using a field as the argument to a function there. Did I understand correctly that `CURDATE()` and by extension `DATE_SUB` are only computed once? Finally, you suggested an index on `UserID,LastReviewed`. Would your advice still apply knowing that the same user can have multiple records with the same `LastReviewed`?

Comment: If this matters to your answer: there already is an index of `UNIQUE UserID,orderID` on that table. `orderID` itself is not unique (multiple users can have the same)

Comment: Such an index could be used to narrow down the rows to the matching user, but the server would have to scan all the matching rows to check the dates.  Better than nothing, but how helpful it is will depend on how many rows per user you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Builtin functions are much less costly than, say, fetching rows.

You could get a lot more performance improvement with the following 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(UserID, LastReviewed)
```

*and* change to

```
WHERE UserID=123
  AND LastReviewed >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
```

Your formulation is 'hiding' `LastRevieded` in a function call, making it unusable in an index.

If you are still not satisfied with that improvement, then consider a nightly query that computes yesterday's statistics and puts them in a "Summary table".  From there, the `SELECT` you mentioned can run even faster.

Comment: The same user can have several records with the same `LastReviewed`, and different users can have records with the same `LasteReviewed`. There is already an index of `Unique UserID, orderID` in the table. Does any of this change your statement about adding a the index `UserID, LastReviewed`?

Comment: My suggested change _plus_ my suggested index should make it run faster.  `UNIQUE(UserID, orderID)` could be used, but it would use only the `UserID` part.  Using both `UserID` and `LastReviewed` will be better.  [_More on composite indexes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1).