# Select column by alias in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to understand certain specific behavior in MySQL. Running "select @@version", I see my version is 5.6.34-log.

Let me put the sample, using a generated table in order to make it easier to reproduce:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(a, b) AS 'c1', CONCAT((SELECT c1), 2)
FROM
    (SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c' UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 3) t1;
```

What I was searching for initially was, as suggested by the title, how to select a column by its alias, in order to reuse calculated fields, avoiding long queries. Most of the answers either suggest using subqueries or variables - one has poor readability, and the other is not assured by the very own DB devs, as stated in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). Then, I learned this method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790702), and can't quite understand it - indeed, I don't even know how to call this kind of operation/clause.

It seems to work very well, at least in this MySQL version. The only exception is when it comes to columns which contains aggregate functions (shown below) - it throws a 1247 (misreference) error, and that feels quite reasonable.

```
-- THIS DOESN'T WORK!
SELECT 
    CONCAT(a, b) AS c1, CONCAT((SELECT c1), 2) as c2
FROM
    (SELECT 'a' as a, 'b' as b, 'c' as c UNION ALL SELECT '1', 2, 3) t1;
```

I've read many answers around this theme, but that is the only reference to this kind of operation, and, since I don't know its name, I can't look deeper into it. Does anyone know how is this structure called, how can I understand it better?

EDIT: I'm not trying to perform that operation shown in the not working query. Indeed, I'm trying to understand MySQL behavior. The already existing questions are enoug to understand how to do that using a subquery, and so on - that is not the point. My main issue is to understand what kind of operation is MySQL performing there and how is it called, since I've never read anything about something like that (would it be a query with an auto select?)

EDIT 2: This post has inspired a more specific and better written question about this MySQL behavior, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793968/why-is-mysql-able-to-resolve-these-column-aliases-when-normally-one-cant-reuse).

Comment: Use derived tables instead.

Comment: @jarlh, Op already said ... not happy with subquries

Comment: You **CANT** reference the alias at the same query level . So you have to repeat the code, use subquery or be a sad person.

Comment: @Rahul, Happy or not happy - without giving any reasons... OP is already having sub-queries, and another one can be needed here.

Comment: if youy can upgrade to last version of MariaDB (10.2),  you can use  window functions, so you can re-use the same query on  more then one level.

Comment: @jarlh, am just mentioning but yes subquery or repeating the expression is only choice.

Comment: When it comes to software maintenance repeating expressions is a bad choice, but sub-queries are fine.

Comment: Well, If I can't reference the alias, why does the first query work?
I know I can use subqueries or so, I'm not asking how to perform that. My point here is manly about why my first query works - I'd like to understand what kind of operation is MySQL doing there.

Comment: And, @jarlh, note that the subquery here is only for providing this sample, as I statead before. What I really can't understand is MySQL behavior and what kind of operation is being performed here. I've already written queries in which I need to set a flag for some case, and reusing that flag column, as it seems to be possible here, would save lots and lots of typing.

Comment: Here `CONCAT((SELECT c1), 2)` is probably getting inlined as `CONCAT(CONCAT(a, b), 2)`

Comment: Does the first query work?!? Amazing, because it's far from valid ANSI SQL in many ways. Anyway, derived tables is the trick to avoid repeated expressions.

Comment: @Rahul, if so, that is the intended behavior, and it is great. I've tested it in many ocasions, and it feels like it is doing exactly that, but I'm trying to be sure, since I've never read any documentation about it.

Comment: @jarlh That is my point all the time, it works and I can't tell why!

Comment: Liking the question more and more.  It is an interesting situation.  It's like the order of operations of the select is left to right; so the alias resolves, then the subquery uses correlation to resolve the alias and thus can concat the alias columns when normally one wouldn't be able to.  simply by using a inline select.  Or as Rahul indicated select c1 is getting inlined by the compiler...

Comment: Yes... At my SQL courses, I've never been presented to it, as, like appointed previously, it seems far from standard SQL.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be documented that I can find, it appears to be a "feature" which leads me to don't trust/use it as it could change on update.  I went as far as rephrasing your question and posting a different one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793968/why-is-mysql-able-to-resolve-these-column-aliases-when-normally-one-cant-reuse to see if it gets more attention.

Comment: Perhaps called Aliased expressions? (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79549)

Comment: @xQbert Link to your new question added in the original question, in order to help visitors to find it.

Comment: It appears to be a mySQL extension; and far from standard SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

1. references to aliases in SELECT list or
2. Aliased expressions

The only documentation I've found on this so far has been:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79549

In that link there is the following:

[9 Dec 2015 15:35] Roy Lyseng
...
Here is a longer background for the original decision:

Contrary to references to aliases in subqueries in the WHERE clause (and in GROUP BY, for that matter), ***there is no reason (except standard compliance) that we should not allow references to aliases in the SELECT list***, since they should be available in the same phase of query execution. But the support in 5.6 was quite arbitrary:

Given this: create table t1(a int, b int),

Alias in SELECT list is not valid:

```
  select a+b as c,c+1 from t1;
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c' in 'field list'

But within a subquery, reference to c is valid:

```
  select a+b as c,(select c+1) from t1;
```

And subquery must be after definition of alias:

```
  select (select c+1),a+b as c from t1;
```

> ERROR 1247 (42S22): Reference 'c' not supported (forward reference in item list)

So, it is easy to say that support for ***references to aliases in SELECT list*** was rather ad-hoc. Nevertheless, we will try to reimplement the old solution, but with no attempt at cleaning up the obvious holes in the support for this feature. But referencing aliases in subqueries in the WHERE clause will not be reimplemented.

I'm yet looking for documentation beyond the bug report describing this functionality in the standard documents; but thus far no luck.

Comment: Well, OP's posted SQL code works too. Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2bd46/1

Comment: Goin to edit the question to fit your tips, and make my point clearer.

Comment: @Rahul odd if I try the same thing on rexTester it comes back service unavailable; but if I try the above it works.  Now I know that's not the issue but strange behavior is different.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same expression again, it wont hurt *Reuse* much like

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(a, b) AS 'c1', CONCAT(CONCAT(a, b), 2)
FROM
    (SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c' UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 3) t1;
```

Comment: You can also do `CONCAT(a, b, 2)` ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Yes you can ... :)

Comment: Well... My expression is quite simple here, this is a sample. When I start using nested IFs, cases, and so forth, it is very hard to understand what is happening

Comment: @LucasLima, then subquery / view / CTE (CTE not supported in MySQL) is the option

Comment: @Rahul, i I understand it. Just edited the question to make it clearer. I know how to do that. I want to understand why shouldn't I use the structure I showed in the question instead, since it is cleaner and works as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(a, b) AS 'c1', CONCAT((SELECT c1), 2)
FROM
(SELECT 'a' a, 'b' b, 'c' c UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 3) t1;
```

Or better, if you have window functions (not on your version of MySQL, but for readers):

```
// only with MariaDB 10.2 and up

WITH q AS (SELECT 'a' a, 'b' b, 'c' c UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 3) 
    SELECT * FROM q WHERE  a='a'
```