# Use MySQL variable only for counting without returning to client in SELECT part

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, vbulletin

#### TL;DR

I use a MySQL variable that got incremented conditionally per row. This variable is only required for the `HAVING` clause, but by force also selected for incrementation.

Is it possible to increment the variable for each row without selecting it value back to the client?

#### Context with explanation and examples

The VBulletin forum software stores thread replys in a `post` table with a column `visible`. 0 means waiting for unlock, 1 visible and 2 soft deleted. I'm working on a MySQL query that fetches the posts of a page (typical 10). Users should only see posts with `visible = 1` but moderators also the others.

First I want to filter based on usergroup. But this would make up my paging chaotic since a post could be on e.g. page 2 for guests, where it is on page 3 for moderators since deleted/not approved posts exists before this page.

For this reason, my concept is to select all post ids and limit only the ones to 10 per page where `visible = 1`. If the first page contains 10 visible posts and 2 deleted posts, then mods would get 12 posts and regular users only 10. But paging is the same for both, since deleted posts doesn't change it.

Inspirated from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085443/can-i-reuse-a-calculated-field-in-a-select-query) I build the following query:

```
SET @visible_sum = 0;

SELECT postid, visible, @visible_sum := @visible_sum + IF(visible = 1, 1, 0)
FROM post
WHERE threadid = 38325
GROUP BY postid
HAVING @visible_sum < 10
ORDER BY dateline;
```

[image]

As you can see, I get 10 non deleted posts and additionally 4 deleted ones (highlighted). With less modifications, this query can be re-used for non moderative users:

```
SELECT postid, visible, @visible_sum := @visible_sum + 1
...
HAVING @visible_sum < 10 AND visible = 1
```

[image]

So this generally works as required. But I don't like the fact that I always get the counter. Only post ids are used in my application, which means `SELECT postid FROM posts ...` would be enough. I don't know a way how it's possible to calculate the variable without using the `SELECT` part, which automatically results in a field of the returned rows to the client. I'm using MySQL, currently on MariaDB 10.1.

Comment: This query looks quite unreliable. However - You can use a subquery and select wich ever columns you need from it.

Comment: I'd be a little cautious with that kind of use of session/@ variable. The rules on when they are evaluated can get kind of murky, and using them outside of initializing them in the FROM and manipulating them in the SELECT can end up with strange results. At very least, I would alias the SELECT expression you have and HAVING against that alias instead; as far as I know while HAVING is handled after the SELECT, there is no _guarantee_ from version to version on whether it is handled after each SELECT result row is determined or all SELECT result rows have been.

Comment: BTW: Your second query could be just `SELECT postid, visible FROM post WHERE threadid = 38325 AND visible = 1 ORDER BY dateline LIMIT 10`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You're right, the second one could be simpler. I had too much focus on the problem with `visibility`. Do you have a better idea how to handle this? I'm open to more stable and performant alternatives (query got slow on large threads).

Comment: @Uueerdo That doesn't sound good. Using the alias works, but do you have another solution for a more reliable and performant way? The main problem seems paging. I need to fetch posts based on pages (e.g. page 3) which isn't too performant. So I'd like to fetch the post ids with this query and then later the posts, which itself gets faster since the large post query contains multiple joins.

Comment: I cannot provide a full answer, because I don't see a clear problem statement. Or I just don't undestand the question. A really good question would provide at least the schema, sample data and the expected result for a single and isolated problem. The question "*Is it possible to increment the variable for each row without selecting it value back to the client?*" is already answered.

Comment: Assuming the "threads" don't have an excessive number of posts, you might be better off just selecting all (or a large number) of `postid`, `visible` for the thread once and paginating over that list (refreshing the list as needed). Or use two queries, one to find the boundary dateline values, and the second to get the posts within those.

Comment: I agree with @PaulSpiegel that this is out of the scope from this question and accepted the answear from Barmar.

Comment: @Uueerdo That's my current workaround. Looking at the problem from two steps back, this seems the better solution than investing much time in saving one query. Since I get the usergroup from the session, I could run the second query only for moderators. Since this affects commonly a few users, the overhead is moderate.

Comment: I would probably just change the requirements (which is advanced development technique :-)). Do the moderators really need 10 visible posts per page? Why not just show 10 any posts per page?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel They don't. But the reason why I want this is pagination. Deleted posts could change pagination so page 6 for a regular user becomes page 7 on moderators. Especially for the link generation on a specific post this is problematic and make things more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your query into a subquery.

```
SELECT postid, visible
FROM (
    SELECT postid, visible, @visible_sum := @visible_sum + IF(visible = 1, 1, 0)
    FROM post
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @visible_sum := 0) AS vars
    WHERE threadid = 38325
    HAVING @visible_sum < 10
    ORDER BY dateline
) AS x
```

You also shouldn't have `GROUP BY postid` when you don't have any aggregation functions.