# MYSQL : Error in results obtained from a query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database:

Structure:
1.> txnorder:

```
CREATE TABLE txnorder (
  orderid int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderfy varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderdate date DEFAULT NULL,
  orderpartycode varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderprdcode varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderpage int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderqpc int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderbdl int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderbox int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  orderfreight varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2.> txnpackingslip :

```
CREATE TABLE txnpackingslip (
  packid int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  packfy varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  packdate date DEFAULT NULL,
  packpartycode int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  packprodcode varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  packpage int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  packqpc int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  packbdl int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  packbox int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  packlocation varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  packfrieght varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  packtransport varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  packtransno varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  packremark varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Dummy Data :

```
insert  into `txnorder`(`orderid`,`orderfy`,`orderdate`,`orderpartycode`,`orderprdcode`,`orderpage`,`orderqpc`,`orderbdl`,`orderbox`,`orderfreight`) values (1,'2019-20','2020-02-04','1','10101',192,236,20,0,'To Pay'),(1,'2019-20','2020-02-04','1','10102',72,100,0,4,'To Pay');


insert  into `txnpackingslip`(`packid`,`packfy`,`packdate`,`packpartycode`,`packprodcode`,`packpage`,`packqpc`,`packbdl`,`packbox`,`packlocation`,`packfrieght`,`packtransport`,`packtransno`,`packremark`) values (1,'2019-20','2020-02-04',1,'10102',72,100,0,1,'ab','To Pay','Andaman and Nicobar Islands','','');
```

On the above mentioned Data, When I execute this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT( o.orderprdcode )                   AS "Code", 
               ( Sum(o.orderbdl) - Sum(p.packbdl) ) AS "Req Bdl", 
               ( Sum(o.orderbox) - Sum(p.packbox) ) AS "Req Box" 
FROM   txnorder o, 
       txnpackingslip p 
WHERE  o.orderpartycode = 1 
       AND o.orderprdcode = p.packprodcode 
GROUP  BY o.orderprdcode 
HAVING ( Sum(o.orderbdl) - Sum(p.packbdl) ) > 0 
        OR ( Sum(o.orderbox) - Sum(p.packbox) ) > 0
```

It gives results with only code : 10102, I want the results for code 10101 also as it also has pending orders.

I've tried left outer join but it did not work for me.
Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions.

When I took a look closely at  @Kandy and @Blake's Answers, I found my required results by combining those suggestions.

now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT(o.orderprdcode)              AS "Code", 
      (SUM(o.orderbdl)-IFNULL(p.packbdl,0)) AS "Req_Bdl", 
      (SUM(o.orderbox)-IFNULL(p.packbox,0)) AS "Req_Box" 
FROM txnorder o LEFT JOIN txnpackingslip p 
ON o.orderprdcode = p.packprodcode 
WHERE o.orderpartycode = 1 GROUP BY orderprdcode 
HAVING req_bdl > 0 OR req_box > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

this happening due to having clause that you are filtering only those data which have value greater than zero and in your case for order 10101 data is not available in second tabel. and if you want 10101 then it will comes with null Values with below query.

**Also use left join**

```
SELECT DISTINCT( o.orderprdcode )                   AS "Code", 
           ( Sum(o.orderbdl) - Sum(ifnull(p.packbdl,0)) ) AS "Req Bdl", 
           ( Sum(o.orderbox) - Sum(ifnull(p.packbox,0)) ) AS "Req Box" 
FROM   txnorder o left join
   txnpackingslip p on  o.orderprdcode = p.packprodcode 
WHERE  o.orderpartycode = 1 
GROUP  BY o.orderprdcode 

--HAVING ( Sum(o.orderbdl) - Sum(p.packbdl) ) > 0 
 --      OR ( Sum(o.orderbox) - Sum(p.packbox) ) >0
```

As per your detailed requirement sql fiddle created http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/625ccb/17

Comment: No, I don't want the null values. I need the actual values. That will be 10101   20   0

Comment: @ArpitPorwal As per your requirement i have change something in query you can check in fiddle itself

Answer (score 1):

I'd break your query down first into two grouped sub queries:-
`CREATE VIEW OrderGrouped as SELECT orderprdcode, SUM(orderbdl) AS sum_orderbdl, SUM(orderbox) AS sum_orderbox FROM txnorder GROUP BY orderprdcode;`
`CREATE VIEW PackingGrouped AS SELECT packprodcode, SUM(packbdl) AS sum_packbdl, SUM(packbox) AS sum_packbox FROM txnpackingslip GROUP BY packprodcode;`
Open these views and make sure you're happy with the sums for the order/pack product codes. It will be much easier to work with the query once you've created the views:-

```
SELECT orderprdcode, 
IFNULL(sum_orderbdl,0)-IFNULL(sum_packbdl,0) AS req_bdl, 
IFNULL(sum_orderbox,0)-IFNULL(sum_packbox,0) AS req_box 
FROM OrderGrouped o
LEFT JOIN PackingGrouped p
ON o.orderprdcode = p.packprodcode 
WHERE (SELECT req_bdl)>0 or (SELECT req_box)>0
```

Note the following:-
Killing the null values using the IFNULL function (the nulls probably caused the issue in the first place)
The SELECT keyword in the WHERE clause to reuse the computed columns in the SELECT clause. I haven't tested this but it was accepted to work (assuming you use a recent enough version of MySQL) in:-
[Can I reuse a calculated field in a SELECT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085443/can-i-reuse-a-calculated-field-in-a-select-query).
If you have problems, just re-type the calculations.

Best of luck with it,

Phil

Comment: Last query throwing an error
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'req_bdl' in 'field list'

Comment: Replace (SELECT req_bdl) with (IFNULL(sum_orderbdl,0)-IFNULL(sum_packbdl,0)) and (SELECT req_box) with (IFNULL(sum_orderbox,0)-IFNULL(sum_packbox,0)). It seems it isn't recognising the computed columns in the WHERE clause