# What's the correct sql syntax for aliases in operations

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the right syntax to calculate the "average ratio"

```
SELECT `account`.`company`,`account`.`name`, `inventory`.`sellernum`,
ROUND(
    AVG(inventory.appraisedprice *
        IF(v_winning_clerks.dateentered >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,3,
           IF(v_winning_clerks.dateentered BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH AND NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,2, 1))), 2) 
    AS "average appraised price",
ROUND(AVG(`v_winning_clerks`.`sellprice`),2) AS "average sell price",
ROUND(AVG("average sell price" / "average appraised price")) as "average ratio"
FROM `v_winning_clerks`
JOIN `inventory` USING(`itemnum`, `auctionnum`)
JOIN `attendance` USING(`auctionnum`, `sellernum`)
JOIN `account` USING(`accountnum`)
GROUP BY `inventory`.`sellernum
```

Comment: (1) I removed the SQL Server tag because the code is clearly MySQL.  (2) Define what you mean by "average ratio".  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Comment: Does [this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790702/1048425)?

Comment: Are you asking what function(s) to use, or how to name alias a column, or re-use an aliased column?

Comment: Your query already use aliases (`AS`). So what's the actual question? Did you get an error? Edit the title and the question itself to actually ask what you want

Comment: it returned null values and it shouldn't have, so I'm wondering what's wrong with that syntax?

Comment: I'm asking how to reuse an alias column in further calculations, what's the right syntax in the function