# Mysql - reusing calculated values

Tags: mysql, variables

I don't know exactly how to word this question but here it is. 
I want to reuse values that i calculated in my query to calculate another value. 
Variables is the correct word i guess. here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.label as label,SUM(t1.totalEvents) as Entry,SUM(t2.totalEvents) as Back,  
    ROUND(Entry/Back*100,2) as 'Rate'
FROM 
    trackReports_daily t1
.... rest of query ...
```

Inside round i want to to use the value returned by SUM(t1.totalEvents), but when i use `Entry` i get this error `Unknown column 'Entry' in 'field list'`

How else can i get the value in there without recalculating everytime like this:

```
ROUND(SUM(t2.totalEvents)/SUM(t1.totalEvents)*100,2)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368084/can-i-re-use-an-expression-in-a-mysql-query-as-a-variable-for-another-field

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I resuse a calculated field in a SELECT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085443/can-i-resuse-a-calculated-field-in-a-select-query)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT label, Entry, Back, ROUND(Entry/Back*100,2) as 'Rate'
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(t1.totalEvents) as Entry, SUM(t2.totalEvents) as Back, t1.label as label
    FROM trackReports_daily t1 
    .... rest of query ... 
) as temp;
```

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at this example

```
select (select @t1:=sum(field1)),(select @t2:=sum(field2)),@t1/@t2 from table
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer. It's so easy to do in MySQL, yet most people that don't know this feature tend to use subqueries.

Comment: According to MySQL documentation "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html Is this solution safe?

Comment: This is not a good practice; results not guaranteed.
MySQL manual: "as a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable...".
"For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed".

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a subquery in the FROM clause like:

```
SELECT 
    t1.label as label,SUM(t1.totalEvents) as Entry,t2.Back,  
    ROUND(t1.Entry/t2.Back*100,2) as 'Rate'
FROM 
    (SELECT *, SUM(totalEvents) as Entry FROM trackReports_daily) t1
    (SELECT *, SUM(totalEvents) as Back FROM someTable) t2
.... rest of query ...
```

If you want to reuse Rate in further queries then it will get complicated, and I do not know if this will have optimal performance, but I think it will do what you asked for in your example.