# Select multiple rows based on two or more seperate dates

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so everything I find out there seems to be BETWEEN two separate dates.  That is NOT what Im trying to do.  Im looking for a solution that selects the row/s based on two or more different dates.

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE DATE(date) IN ('2012-11-30','2012-11-01')
```

Just trying to draw out the information for those two dates.  Thanks a ton in advance for your help!

Comment: What you have doesn't work?  A simple `dateField = "2012-11-30" OR dateField = "2012-11-01"` doesn't work?  Are these `DATETIME` columns, and you need to strip off the time component?

Comment: yes they are DATETIME columns and I only want the date w/out the time component.  Works just fine with Date(date) = '2012-11-30' but I cant seem to get it to draw out multiple dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
    WHERE DATE(`date`) = "2012-11-30" OR DATE(`date`) = "2012-11-01";
```

Comment: Worked great.  Is there any way to do it without having to repeat DATE(date) every time?

Comment: @user791187, Sort of.  To my knowledge, the only way to do it would be to use a subquery.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6363289/362536